# Error with CGRect

Tags: ios, cgrect

My App is working properly, but when i analyzeing it X-code show me this

[image]

What's that mean?

Can anyone help?

Comment: "Right click – copy image url – open in new tab" feels so long -> please resize your image… But CGRectZero is your friend because it might be uninitialized depending on your Interface_Idiom

Comment: Your rect is has no frame for iPad version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CGRect rect = CGRectZero;` will fix it.

"argument contains uninitialised data" means an argument in your case `rect` might be passed uninitialised as a method argument in `UIImageView *splashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect]`. This happens if the first `if` statement fails then `else` is triggered which does not set the frame.

You need to either set the default value outside the `if-else` as shown above or set the rect values in the `else` block as well.

You should know all the primitives/structures have no initial value by default and those values are garbage. A simple example of same error would be:

```
int i; //at this point the i may have any value
i = i+1;
```

Comment: Hi, that may be so... but it's often good practice to explain why ;) Don't forget there are total newbies on this site who might be able to learn a thing or two from you :)

Comment: You are right, though I have no idea how to explain it better then the analyser "argument contains uninitialised data"

Comment: "initialize it with a new instance of... because that's what is causing it to throw the error when..." :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not supply CGRect which is not initialised. If your code will run for iPad, ivar `rect` will be supplied to view without initialisation. So, either you can supply some default value at the time of creation or you need to write proper value in `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

That `if` statement has an `else` where `rect` is not initialised...

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize rect for iPad or remove else from main if.